# Tsql IN clause with empty subset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dbnull, in-subquery

Is it possible to set an `IN` statement that also matches an empty subset?

This is my query:

```
.. WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM #subset)
```

I would like that record also if `#subset` is empty.
A workaround would be:

```
.. WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #subset) OR id IN (SELECT * FROM #subset)
```

However the (`SELECT * FROM #subset`) is not a so simply query and I would like to know is there is a smart way to use "IN" also with empty subset.

Comment: How is #subset prepared? A temp table (as indicated)? Or is it shorthand for a query?

Answer (score 3):

Use a double negative expression.

Instead of

> where rows exist that match

.. this is

> where no rows exists that don't match

```
DECLARE @m TABLE (KeyCol int, Payload varchar(2));
DECLARE @s TABLE (KeyCol int);

INSERT @m VALUES (1, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (3, 'cc');

-- No values in #subset
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @m M
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @s S WHERE M.KeyCol <> S.KeyCol);

INSERT @s VALUES (2);

-- A matching value in #subset
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @m M
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @s S WHERE M.KeyCol <> S.KeyCol);
```

Of course, the correlated EXISTS WHERE clause can be extended to multiple columns (unlike the IN clause which expects only one column)